# Implementing efficient parallel map and reduce in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

Given the following examples in Python, I would like to know how to implement equivalent code in Haskell that is also efficient and parallel.

First example in Python: functional map

```
f = lambda x: 2*x
print map(f, [1,2,3,4])
```

Second example in Python: functional reduce

```
g = lambda x,y: x*y
print reduce(g, [1,2,3,4], 1)
```

I would like the parallel code in Haskell to be able to efficiently exploit multicore processors.

Note: These are just toy examples, I don't intend to have speedups with these toy examples. They are just meant to illustrate how to implement the operators map and reduce in parallel with Haskell.

Comment: Try reading https://wiki.haskell.org/Applications_and_libraries/Concurrency_and_parallelism Also, `parMap` from `Control.Parallel.Strategies` could solve the first, albeit for very simple functions like those above it could also make performance worse.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please tell us what you have tried, and show us some effort on your side. How much haskell do you already know. Using multiple cores is usually not a beginners problem. You might find some information in [Simon Marlowe's excellent book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929). Also before going parallel - just check if the simple single core solution is fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

For the functional map, an equivalent sequential version in Haskell would be:

```
f x = 2*x
dxs = map f [1,2,3,4]
main = print dxs
```

A parallel version in Haskell would be:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.Parallel

f x = 2*x
dxs = parMap rpar f [1,2,3,4]
main = print(dxs)
```

Comment: I guess this is the most efficient way of implementing the map operator in parallel with Haskell. Let me know if there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is

```
import Control.Parallel

newtype PMonoid a = PM {unPM :: a}

instance Monoid a => Monoid (PMonoid a) where
    mempty = PM mempty
    (PM a) <> (PM b) = PM (a `par` b `pseq` a <> b)
```

This will make [`foldMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap) parallel. (In particular, the map operation gains parallelism by virtue of laziness.)

You many want to incoporate [`deepseq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq), but it not necesarrily necessary.